# Relationship between power and $p$-value

Tags: p-value, statistical-power

As the title states, I wish to understand the relationship between $p$-value, of a correlation coefficient say, and the power of this hypothesis test.

Suppose I observe a Pearson correlation coefficient of $r = 0.3$ in a sample of $n=50$ pairs. I can then hop over to [this calculator](https://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/pearsondistribution.aspx), and quickly compute a $p$-value of $.034$.

Is is then valid for me to use this $p$-value in G*Power as below, in order to conclude that the power of this test is $0.52$?

**Addendum:** If this calculation is false, what quantity can I compare with desired power $1 - \beta$, analogous to how the $p$-value is compared with the desired significance level $\alpha$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, yes, this is valid. There is a one-to-one relationship between any two of sample size, power, effect size and alpha level: if you fix two of them and vary a third, then the fourth will vary with the third one, monotonically.

Therefore, the insights you can derive from this kind of exercise are very limited indeed.

For an in-depth argument, see [Hoenig & Heisey, "The Abuse of Power - The Pervasive Fallacy of Power Calculations for Data Analysis", *The American Statistician*, 2012](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313001300339897).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I asked because I was wondering how one would go about controlling for type II error if one were to employ a decision-theoretic approach to significance levels (https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/66373/1/MPRA_paper_66373.pdf) But perhaps my idea here is not the way to do go about it...I will have to look over the article you linked to.

Comment: Hm. That link is not working for me.

Comment: This article is better, actually: Kim, J.H. and Choi, I. (2021), Choosing the Level of Significance: A Decision‐theoretic Approach. Abacus, 57: 27-71. https://doi.org/10.1111/abac.12172

Comment: [Abuse of Power---ungated link](http://bendixcarstensen.com/SDC/CIMT/Hoenig.2001.pdf)